# createStatement method implemented by Oracle Driver or JDK

Tags: java, jdbc

In Jdbc,the statement was created after successfully created connection then we are called

st=conn.createStatement()

My Question is The statemenet object created above.But **createstatement()** method implemenation by Oracle type drivers or JVM.if any wrong with question sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC only defines a database-independent interface for vendor-specific drivers to implement.

So, createStatement is *defined* by the JDK, but *implemented* by (in your case) the Oracle driver. There are different implementations for different databases by the other vendors.

If you print the class names of the objects created by your driver, you should see class names with "Oracle" in them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer by Thilo, createStatement() is defined by the JDBC API which is included in your JDK. JDBC API is a set of interfaces.
 And oracle driver will create the implementation for the interface methods e.g. createStatement()
If you use sql server db instead of oracle, the implementation will be created by sql server db.